# d3.js : Highlight path upto root node on mouse event of a node

Tags: d3.js

I have created a tree diagram based on https://i.stack.imgur.com/17hpU.jpg

I would like to add a feature which will highlight the path upto root node when any node is selected. As I am new and not know how to define a root as well as how to highlight the path. could someone give some useful links on how to achieve that?

Comment: Could you make a fiddle of what you have so far?

Comment: I have created the fiddle for the first time and I don't know how to paste the json data. Kindly find the fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/B3U66/2/ Thanks for reply.

Comment: You could just use `var data = [...all your JSON stuff here...]`. JSON is just JavaScript Object Notation, so it's perfectly valid to put the data with your JS.

Comment: [This post](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2011/08/progressive-reveal-animations-in-svg-using-a-svgclippath/) has the information and example you need.